# How to maintain state of checkboxes and radiobutton in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am building a search page using asp.net mvc.
The page would have two text search fields and few search parameters based on checkbox and radio button.
How can I maintain the state of checkboxes and radio button once the result comes back ?
Some of these checkboxes may be dynamically generated too.

Comment: I would suggest Ajax to only do a partial post and then you would not refresh the entire page and keep the state of the checkbook and radio button. Or send the values of those in the post

Answer (score 0):

You should send the data every time between the view and the controller with a model and rebuild your status manually.

but please try to use ajax calls in your app so you don't need to refresh the page in every user action.